# Cant authorise nested resources with Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, authorization, pundit

Here is my problem. I have multiple users with multiple subscriptions each and i want to authorise subscriptions index method with Pundit.
My **routes.rb**:

```
resources :users do
   resources : subscriptions
end
```

Lets assume i'm user with id **1**. What i need is to get list of subscriptions when i open `/users/1/subscriptions` and Pundit access error when i open `/user/2/subscriptions`

Here is my subscriptions_controller.rb

```
SubscriptionController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @subscriptions = @user.subscriptions

        authorize @subscriptions
    end
end
```

I can do `authorize @user, :subscriptions_index`, but it just feels wrong to write user policy for subscription authentication. How should i approach this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you (might not be the most efficient):

```
class SubscriptionController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    # this should either return the same or an empty association
    @subscriptions = @user.subscriptions
    authorize @subscriptions
  end
end

class SubscriptionPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index?
    # asking if all subscriptions have the current_user id as the user_id
    record.all? {|sub| sub.user_id == user.id }         
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but as you pointed out it's not most efficient

Comment: If you are looking for the most efficient, then you should amend your question to ask for that.

Comment: @nikkon226 What if a user has no subscriptions? Doesn't this policy allow you through to the path in that case?

Comment: You could call the policy directly with a nil value inside a raise. It's described further down [this section](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/blob/master/README.md#policies) of the Pundit documentation.